# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'list1' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables

I am not writing my entire code. But this is the main part where I am getting an error.

I have 2 functions inside class T. I am declaring global variable in my first function and using that variable in my second function. I am not able to change the value of the global variable in my second function though i can modify it .

I am getting this error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'list1' referenced before assignment 
I am getting error at the last line. If I removed that it works properly.

```
    class T:

       def selectAllCities(self):
            global a,b,list1,list2
            a = T.cities()
            b = T.population()
            list1 = [a,b]
            list2 = [[],[]]
            return a,b,list1,list2

        def printcities(self,attribute,*argv):
            if not list2[0] and not list2[1]:
                if len(argv) > 0:
                    lowerBound = argv[0]
                    upperBound = argv[1]
                    if (attribute[0] == 'n')
                        for x in list1[1]:
                            list2[1].append(x)
                        for n in list1[0]:  
                            list2[0].append(n)
                        print("Name: %s\nPopulation: %s "%(list2[0],list2[1]))
                        list1 = [[],[]]

t = T() 
t.selectAllCities():
t.printcities("name",50,100):
```

Comment: If that is your full code, you are not using `global` properly. The `global` statement does not declare a global, it indicates to modify the `list1` in the global space. However, why are you using `global`? You have a class, why not make an attribute?

Comment: You have a bunch of globals declared, but have not shared the code which declares those globals.  How can we be expected to help?

Comment: How should I make an attribute so that I can change my list1 and let that be global too

Comment: Why are you using globals???  Explain that, and then you might get a reasonable answer on how to use globals.

Comment: @VaibhavBorkar You should *really* read the tutorial on classes to understand how to leverage its usage properly. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) is the documentation.

Comment: I am using globals because I need to use the original values used in function selectAllCities() again later

Comment: That is not a good reason.  Pass the values into the methods.  Do not use globals for this....

Comment: I suggest creating instance attributes in an `__init__` and then modify them as needed in your methods. Using `globals` here is incorrect. You need to understand what it means to have instance attributes and how data in your objects persist. The best use of your time right now is to go back and review how classes work in Python.

Comment: Listen to @idjaw, he speaks truth and gives good references to boot....

Comment: @idjaw Yes I will try to understand that concept properly! But if I define the values in __init__ will I be able to change it in another function?

Comment: @StephenRauch Yes I will. Thanks!

Comment: @VaibhavBorkar Yes. Studying up on classes will help greatly as well as 
 general object-oriented concepts.

Comment: @VaibhavBorkar yes, you will. There is almost never a good reason to use `globals`, especially not in your user-defined classes, methods etc.

Comment: Alright! Thank you